# why is the directory trimmed from my path argument in includegraphics?

Tags: external-files, paths, arguments

Hi community I have a weird problem. It seems that `includegraphics` won't accept the entire argument, it always trims off the directory part!

The argument was manipulated and concatenated in another command before passing to the concerned command. But `\typeout` the argument shows that the argument contains correct string. What happened!?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\setInset}[6]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname useInset#1\endcsname{1}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname inset#1Color\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname crop#1X\endcsname{#3}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname crop#1Y\endcsname{#4}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname crop#1W\endcsname{#5}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname crop#1H\endcsname{#6}%
}

\newcommand{\addInset}[2]{%
    \color{#2}%
    \typeout{OMG #1}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{{#1}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addInsets}[2][1]{%
    \filename@parse{#2}
    \StrSubstitute{\filename@base.\filename@ext}{.}{-}[\tmpName]
    \def\baseFileName{\filename@area\tmpName}
            % setting \cropfile manually works! e.g.
            % \def\cropfile{figures/lr_img_053-png-19.25x19.25+176.5+123.75}
            \def\cropfile{\baseFileName-19.25x19.25+176.5+123.75} 
            \addInset{\cropfile.png}{\insetAColor} % works if I hardcode \addInset{figures/\cropfile.png}

}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}\centering
            \setInset{A}{red}{176.5}{123.75}{19.25}{19.25}
            \addInsets{figures/lr_img_053.png}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Calling `\mycommand{red}{figures/figure.png}` always gives me error `Not found`.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @samcarter please have a look now :)

Comment: Are all your images in the folder `figures`? If yes, I'd simply suggest to add it to the graphic path.

Comment: What's the purpose of inserting `.` and then to change it into `-`? Wouldn't it be simpler to directly do `\edef\baseFileName{\filename@area\filename@base-\filename@ext}`?

Comment: yeah except there might be other `.` i wanna change `-` in the base and ext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includegraphics` uses `\filename@parse` internally. Because you used `\def\cropfile` instead of `\edef\cropfile`, `\baseFileName` isn't expanded and depends on the value of `\filename@area`. `\filename@parse` inside `\includegraphics` overwrites the value of `\filename@area` before expanding the argument, so it sees the value of `\filename@area` it already reset instead of the value assigned by your `\filename@parse` in `\addInsets`.

So you can fix this like @Ian Thompson suggested by writing

```
\edef\cropfile{\baseFileName-19.25x19.25+176.5+123.75}
```

instead of

```
\def\cropfile{\baseFileName-19.25x19.25+176.5+123.75}
```

or by renaming your version of `\filename@area`:

```
\newcommand{\addInsets}[2][1]{%
    \filename@parse{#2}
    \let\myFileArea\filename@area % \edef could be used here too
    \StrSubstitute{\filename@base.\filename@ext}{.}{-}[\tmpName]
    \def\baseFileName{\myFileArea\tmpName}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm too tired to work out what's going on here, but the problem seems to go away if you change `\def` to `\edef` in

```
\def\cropfile{\baseFileName-19.25x19.25+176.5+123.75}
```